# Can't retrieve saved value in sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to save the token wich i got from login activity, in shared preferences ,so when the user reopens the app,if token is the same as token in shared preferences it goes to SecondActivity if not it goes to LoginActivity
i tried a lot but can't get it to work , please help

Methods class responsible for saving and retrevieng data

```
public class SesionManagement {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "STORAGEBAY";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "token";

    public SesionManagement(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }
    public void createLoginSession(String name){
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void checkLogin(String value,String gotValue){

        if(value==gotValue) {
            Toast.makeText(_context, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, NavDraver.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

How i do it in LoginActivity onCreate

```
 session=new SesionManagement(getApplicationContext());
  HashMap<String, String> tokens = session.getUserDetails();
  String name = tokens.get(session.KEY_NAME);
  if(token!=null) {
  session.checkLogin(token, name);
  }
```

then i store the value  in LoginActivity onPostExecute

```
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
          session.createLoginSession(token);

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: your hasmap is tokens.. what then is token? in your code

Comment: acces_token, i get it from Json response in loginActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out first of all

```
 public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tokens.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, ""));
    return tokens;
}
```

questions arising is 1 what if this is the first time the user is logging in? which means `pref.getString(KEY_NAME, "")` is empty.. unless you handle the registration in a diff class

this wasn't an issue when you used `value==gotValue` but now that your are using `value.equals(gotValue)` it checks if the two objects are equal but since one is null there is a null pointer exception..

also this `session.createLoginSession(token);` is called in `onPostExecute` when you are done, and  `session.createLoginSession(token);` is the method that stores your token value
so unless you store this value during registration there will be a NPE..

also in your `doInBackground` you do this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, NavDraver.class);
i.putExtra("cjson",c.toString());
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

it might work for you but its not proper coding-(that is might also flop).. i suggest you put the intent in `onPostExecute` of your code because it is called when your `doInBackground` is done so start the intent there and also call `startActivity(i)` before you call `finish();

and also

```
if(value.matches(gotValue)) {
        Toast.makeText(_context, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i think your toast message should be success shouldnt it?? by the conversion of your code (that's jux btw)

so to sum it up during your `onPostExecute` try this

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        session.createLoginSession(token);
        tokens = session.getUserDetails();
        SavedToken = tokens.get(session.KEY_NAME);
        Log.d("SAVED TOKEN",SavedToken);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

this means declare the intent public to the async task class.. so it could be accessed in `onPostExecute` and  `doInBackground`
hopes all these helps..

lastly copy and paste this

```
public void checkLogin(String value,String gotValue){
     if(value == null && gotValue == null && value.isEmpty() && gotValue.isEmpty()){
        return;
       }else{
     if(value.matches(gotValue)) {
        Toast.makeText(_context, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, NavDraver.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }
    else{
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

to help remove NPE

Edit 2: ok i think i found something

```
private String token, none,SavedToken; //look at token..
```

now you have not instantiated it anywhere before you called `session.checkLogin(token, name); take a look at what i have at paste of code`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    session=new SesionManagement(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> tokens = session.getUserDetails();
    SavedToken = tokens.get(session.KEY_NAME);


    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPass);
    mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

it was later in your doinbackground code that you instantiated it `token = c.getString(TAG_TOKEN);` so i suggest after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);` instantiate token to an empty value `token = "default value should be here"`

Comment: thank you a lot, about the first question i thauch that this is the 
default value,if no token was got ,
about the session.createLoginSession(token) ,if i don't have a registration users just logs in , there is no way to actualy compair the values?

Comment: i dont get you.. but about comparing the values the equals() function compares them.. so the last code i wrote copy and paste it in the checklogin method and check if it works @Alex

Comment: i'm sorry , i wanted to save the token when user logs in , and then it expires user goes to login again ,i did as you said , but still i have the null pointer exception ,in oncreate on line 'session.checkLogin(token,SavedToken);',but it's because the token in oncreate is null so i need to somehow fix it,thank you again a lot for wasting youre time and helping me ,this question of mine was dumb from the start the codding of login form via json is bad to , i will try to recode it maybe i will have an idea how to pull this out,thank you again

Comment: Oh @Alex dont worry ayt..im gud.. check my edit starting from edit2..let me know if it helps or if NPE persist

Comment: also check add to your checklogin() method to check for a default value okay and instatiate the token with that default value so you eliminate the NPE and also when ever the value is that default value it continues with the login like this.. ima edit shortly..sorry also for my inconsistency @Alex

Comment: ive ediited the paste of code you gave me.. [so check it](http://paste.ofcode.org/ZDuRiyHukUvjF4BRDNrAJ8)

Comment: yes it got rid of the NPE , thank you again , now i will have to think of a method to compare the 2 token , the new one and the saved one , again thank you for youre time

Comment: the code i wrote compares the two and also compares if its a default value or not run it and try to login and see..@Alex

Comment: yes sir , you are code is grate :D , it's me the dumb ship , i thoutch that i could compare the token with the token in oncreate , but this is imposible , so i think i will do a time bomb to delete the saved token when it's expires,because i can't get the token right in oncreate it's got only if user clicks login , thank you again youre answer helped me a lot , i learned new stuff so it's more than a great answer , it's a lesson learnt from a good guy who i don't even know :D , but stil you can't imagine how thankful i'm to you )

Comment: well appreciate yourself because your codes are great just a little error that you made, we all make errors that's why i signed up here, also to ask questions that buffled me.. you are great, you are not dumb, it takes time, but  shortly you will be good.. and thanks. and be thanks to you too.. keep on googling and googling about topics you are about to programm about before you start programming, it gives you a good foresight on what you are about to do.. well happy coding and i wish you success... +1 for pushing hard  @Alex

Answer (score 1):

everything looks good but its because of this line

```
 public void checkLogin(String value,String gotValue){

    if(value==gotValue) {  //this line
        Toast.makeText(_context, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, NavDraver.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

change to

```
if(value.equals(gotValue)) or  if(value.matches(gotValue))
```

play around them.. Let me know if it helps

Comment: i tried, i get a null pointer on this line , may it be because i don't save the value how it should be saved

Comment: which line do you get NPE

Comment: at baymd.baymd.library.SesionManagement.checkLogin(SesionManagement.java:33)
if(value.equals(gotValue))
i tried both but still same error , i can post my full login activity

Comment: i got the problem , the token in oncreate is null , now i will have to think how to make token to not be null in oncreate

Comment: have you solved it?, if not then paste it and let me help you re-programme it @Alex

Comment: i haven't solved it , i can't think of something , i think i think and i always hit a wall

Comment: if i post my code from login activity and second activity , and SesionManagment class, will it do ?

Comment: if you could contact me on skype ,exeeld